# Constructing an isomorphism between permutation of three elements and sign flips

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-matrices

It is known that the set of orientation preserving symmetries of a cube is isomorphic to the symmetric group of four letters, $S_4$. Since each of the different orientations can be described by a permutation matrix with signed non-zero elements such that the determinant is equal to one (to preserve orientation), I was wondering how you could construct the isomorphism explicitly between the set of these matrices and the set $S_4$. To be explicit, the rotation matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 \\0 & - 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ corresponds to the permutation $(1)(23)$ where the sign of $2$ is flipped and in principle we can denote this signed permutation by $((1)(23), (+, -, +))$. Therefore I was wondering how you could construct and an isomorphism between these signed permutations and $S_4$.

While I've seen a clever way to label the vertices of the cube as $1,2,3,4$ in order to represent any combination of rotations as a permutation of the four elements, I'm still curious on how you could establish explicitly the that $S_4$ is isomorphic to particular signed permutations of $S_3$ (which in turn correspond to the said signed permutation matrices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know what you mean by “signed permutations of $S_3$ (which correspond to the said signed permutation matrices)”; I’ll assume that that’s just a wrong formulation and what you actually mean is what you wrote further up.

To map the orientation-preserving symmetries of the cube to signed permutation matrices, place the cube with its centre at the origin of a Cartesian coordinate system and express the symmetries as matrices in that coordinate system.

To map the symmetries to elements of $S_4$, consider how they permute the four body diagonals (ignoring inversions).

For instance, the rotations through $\frac\pi2$ about the three coordinate axes map to the matrices $\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0}$, $\pmatrix{0&0&-1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0}$ and $\pmatrix{0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&1}$, and for a certain labelling of the body diagonals they map to the permutations $(1234)$, $(1243)$ and $(1423)$ in $S_4$, respectively. You can generate all the other correspondences from those, or read them off the body diagonals, as you prefer.

Comment: By "*signed permutations of $S_3$ (which correspond to the said signed permutation matrices)*" I meant that if we were to take e.g. $(1)(23)$ of $S_3$ and also consider the sign flips of its elements $(\pm 1)(\pm2\pm3)$ then the first matrix you listed could be identified as the mapping $1 \mapsto 1, 2 \mapsto -3, 3 \mapsto 2$ or as the element $((1)(23), (+, -, +))$ where the second element of the tuple corresponds to the signs of the elements after permutation.  The problem I have with this approach (which funny enough I figured as I'm writing this) is that I couldn't get the algebra to work

Comment: See the edited body for more information.

Comment: @SickSeries: It's not clear to me now what the question is. In the first part you say you want an isomorphism between the signed permutations matrices and $S_4$ – I believe I've answered that. Now you've introduced a different notation for the permutation matrices, but if I understand correctly, it's just a different notation and you know how to write each permutation matrix in this notation you've invented; so I don't know what part of the question remains – you can just write what I wrote as signed permutation matrices in your other notation if you prefer. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think what I really wanted was to see how the algebra would work with the said signed permutations, as the matrix description gives a detailed way of how one should rotate the cube. While I accept that $S_4$ contains exactly the same information, it is now clear to me what I should do exactly with the cube to produce the effect of e.g. the permutation $(1)(2)(34)$. But I suppose that this method will just end up being a more bloated way of describing the different orientations when compared to the $S_4$ method you provided.

Comment: Funny, just as I wrote the previous comment, I came across [this](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~acwood/files/notes/geometricrepresentations.pdf) small paper describing the rotations of the cube with the elements of $S_4$.